# Can I remove <br>s from .html in .css?

Tags: css

I use media queries and I'd like to remove all `<br>` tags from div in css. Is it possible without scripts?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>  
<body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove all `br` tags from all `div` tags by implementing the following rule in your stylesheet:

```
div br {
  display: none;
}
```